# Python - Accessing dictionary inside of list

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

Following instructions from more advanced programmers here (see my previous questions if you want background) I stored my information in a dictionary that is INSIDE a list. (sorry for my confusion, I am learning as I go along)

The problem is that I want to have access to it now through Pandas, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong and what code do I need to make it work?
Thank you

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    #driver.get("https://coinmunity.co/")
    url = 'file:///C:/Users/nique/PycharmProjects/untitled/test1.html'
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')

    #html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    results = []

    row = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/table/tbody/tr')

    for el in row[1:4]:
        symbol = el.find_element_by_class_name('coin-link')
        print('I am symbol  >>>>>>>>>>>>', symbol.text)

        followers = el.find_element_by_class_name('stats')
        print('I am followers  >>>>>>>>>>>>', followers.text)

        results.append({'Symbol': symbol.text, 'TFollowers': followers.text})

    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df.head()
```

Everything is being recorded inside the dictionary as it should, but the last two lines of code to show the results on Pandas, do nothing at all!
PS/ Could it be because I am coding over PyCharm, or something is wrong with the code?

Comment: What is `results` before the DataFrame is created?

Comment: "results" is blank at the beginning and populated by the content of "symbol" and "followers" later. After populating the dictionary by running the loop, the print out of "results" looks like this:
[{'Symbol': 'VEN', 'TFollowers': '87,972'}, {'Symbol': 'ARN', 'TFollowers': '8,628'}]

Comment: Works fine for me using that list.

Comment: ... you never print anything with regards to `df`, so I wouldn't expect to *see anything*.

Comment: Oh wow @juanpa.arrivillaga you are totally right! Beginner's mistake. I just needed to write print(df.head())
Thank you very much to both of you. Should I delete this question for being stupid, or what should I do next here?